# VBA: fill a column with a repeating list of values from another column

Tags: vba, excel

In column B of Sheet1 I have a list of divisions that coincide with ship dates. I need the divisions to be copied from Sheet1(columnB) to Sheet2(columnC). The divisions go from row 3 to 17 and once the macro gets to the division in row 17 I need it to start over with the division in row 3 and add to the bottom of the column. Here is what I have but it doesn't give me any output.

```
For i = 2 To 2
    For y = 3 To 17
        x = x + 1
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 3).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, i).Value
    Next y
Next i
```

#### Input:

```
Atlanta  
Cincinnati  
Columbus  
Michigan  
Central  
Louisville  
Delta  
Nashville  
Mid-Atlantic  
Southwest  
Charleston  
Indiana  
Southwest  
Dillon  
California
```

#### Output:

```
Atlanta  
Cincinnati  
Columbus  
Michigan  
Central  
Louisville  
Delta  
Nashville  
Mid-Atlantic  
Southwest  
Charleston  
Indiana  
Southwest  
Dillon  
California  
Atlanta  
Cincinnati  
Columbus  
Michigan  
Central  
Louisville  
Delta  
Nashville  
Mid-Atlantic  
Southwest  
Charleston  
Indiana  
Southwest  
Dillon  
California
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "start over with the division in row 3". Please provide an example input and the expected output.

Comment: Atlanta
Cincinnati
Columbus
Michigan
Central
Louisville
Delta
Nashville
Mid-Atlantic
Southwest
Charleston
Indiana
Southwest
Dillon
California
Atlanta
Cincinnati
Columbus
Michigan
Central
Louisville
Delta
Nashville
Mid-Atlantic
Southwest
Charleston
Indiana
Southwest
Dillon
California

Comment: I meant provide the sample input/output in the actual question.

Comment: It won't allow me to put the input and output in column form. The output is basically going to be the same list as the input just reiterated x amount of times.

Comment: What you have is good enough. :) And it looks like you have a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your Outer For Loop `For i = 2 To 2` runs only once, change it to `For i = 1 To 2` to run two times and n to run n times etc

```
x = 3
For i = 1 To 2
    For y = 3 To 17            
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 3).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 2).Value
        x = x + 1
    Next y        
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single loop, might be easier if you instantiate a few range variables. As others have noted, your outer loop is beginning at "2" and ending at "2", so that is why it is not repeating as you intend.

```
Sub fillValues()

Dim i As Integer
Dim howManyTimes as Integer
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim rowCount as Long

howManyTimes = 2   'modify as needed; tells the procedure how many times to loop

'## Define the range to "copy"
Set copyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:C17")
'## Get the # of rows in this range
rowCount = copyRange.Rows.Count

'## Define the original destination to "paste":
Set pasteRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") 'this will be modified later


'## Loop and input the values:
For i = 1 To howManyTimes
    pasteRange.Offset((i - 1) * rowCount).Resize(row.Count).Value = copyRange.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Sheet2")

set rng = sht1.Columns(2).UsedRange
j = 1 ' Change for where you want it to start

for each cell In rng.cells
    sht2.cells(1,j) = cell
    j = j + 1
next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this pretty easily without VBA. In column C of `Sheet2`, enter:

`=INDEX($B$3:$B$17,MOD(ROW(C1)-ROW($C$1),COUNTA($B$3:$B$17))+1)`

And just copy down as far as you want to go. Change `$C$1` to the first row of the `Sheet2` column.

---

OPTIONAL:

I also suggest using Named Ranges to make life easier when you come back a year later and can't remember what you were doing. So, do:

`Formulas`->`Define Name`->`DivisionsList` in `Name` field, `=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$17` in `Refers to:` field->`OK`

And:

`Formulas`->`Define Name`->`FirstRow` in `Name` field, `=Sheet2!$C$1` in `Refers to:` field->`OK`

Then just enter this in Column C of `Sheet2` and copy down:

`=INDEX(DivisionsList,MOD(ROW(C1)-ROW(FirstRow),COUNTA(DivisionsList))+1)`

Change the address of `FirstRow` as necessary.